# Vor- oder Nachname, um mit einer Person über eine andere zu sprechen

Tags: politeness, person-names

Ich habe zwei Kollegen: Hans Müller und Josef Meier. Ich bin mit beiden "per Du", spreche also beide mit dem Vornamen an. Die beiden sind untereinander "per Sie", sprechen sich gegenseitig also mit dem Nachnamen an.

Wenn ich nun mit Hans über Josef Meier spreche, verweise ich auf ihn dann als Josef, also so, wie ich ihn direkt ansprechen würde, oder als Herr Meier, also so,b wie Hans ihn ansprechen würde?

Comment: Wenn du Schmidt heisst und verheiratet bist, sprichst du dann mit deinem Kollegen von ihr als Frau Schmidt oder nennst du sie beim Vornamen?

Comment: @tofro: Wahrscheinlich würde ich von den zwei Optionen eher den Vornamen verweden. Solange meine Kollgen meine Frau nicht direkt kennen würde ich aber eher "meine Frau" verwenden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wichtig für die Frage kann sein, ob Hans (der Angesprochene) weiß, dass Du mit Josef per Du bist. Dann ist die Frage, wieso für die Frage wichtig sein soll, ob Du mit Hans per Du bist. Spielen Hierarchie- und Respektfragen mit rein? 
Zum dritten, ob es weitere Zuhörer der Konversation gibt und welches Vorwissen die über Eure Verhältnisse haben, ob die nur beiläufig mithören oder in einer formalen Sitzung eine Zuhörerrolle einnehmen. Ist Josef, über den gesprochen wird, selbst unter den Zuhörern?

In formalen Situationen benutzt man nicht selten den Nachnamen, auch um  Neutralität gegenüber allen Personen auszudrücken. Es hängt von der konkreten Situation ab, ob das wichtig ist.

Es kann aber auch gerade die Intention sein, die Konvention zu durchbrechen und Dein persönliches Verhältnis zu unterstreichen.

Das Duzen kann eine Auszeichnung sein, weil es eine größere Intimität ausdrückt. Es kann aber auch herabsetzend verstanden werden, da man Kinder unterschiedslos duzt.

Ich würde also 3 Kriterien nennen: Haben die Zuhörer genügend Kontextwissen, um zu verstehen, wie die Bezeichnungsform gemeint ist? Gelten in der Situation Konventionen, denen zu folgen sich empfiehlt? Willst Du Dein persönliches Verhältnis betonen oder abschwächen?

Im Fernsehen hat man gelegentlich den Fall, dass Reporter o. Moderatoren die Gäste üblicherweise Siezen, aber einen oder mehrere Gesprächspartner hinter den Kulissen duzen. Dann wenden sie sich gelegentlich ans Publikum, erklären diesem, dass dem so ist, und sich im Gespräch ein Siezen für sie falsch anfühlen würde. Wenn es aber mehrere Gesprächspartner gibt, manche werden geduzt, manche gesiezt, dann bleibt für den Zuschauer die Ungleichbehandlung störend.

Comment: Kurz zusammengefasst: Verwende die Form die sich für die Situation richtig anfühlt und hoffe niemanden vor den Kopf zu stoßen. ;) Wie ich eigentlich bereits erwartet habe, gibt es auf meine Frage wohl keine einfache, eindeutige Antwort.

Answer (score 5):

Eine Regel gibt es dafür nicht, ich würde

> Herr Meier

empfehlen, dann gibt es keine Irritationen. Unter Umständen weiß Herr Müller ja gar nicht, dass Herr Meier Josef heißt. Und im Übrigen ist es grundsätzlich höflicher, wenn man sich dem Gesprächspartner anpasst.

Comment: "im Übrigen ist es grundsätzlich höflicher, wenn man sich dem Gesprächspartner anpasst" - na, ob mein Lehrer so erfreut gewesen wäre, hätte ich ihm gegenüber seine Kollegen Ulla und Hans-Jörg (mit denen *er* natürlich per Du war) erwähnt, statt von Frau Schnesenberg und Herrn Rippelmeier zu sprechen ...?

Comment: Die Überlegung, dem einen könnte der Vorname des anderen unbekannt sein, ist offensichtlich nicht die Sorge, die raznagul trieb.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Dann läge der Formfehler (wenn man so will) aber beim Lehrer, der seine Spezis in deiner Gegenwart nicht Ulla und Hans-Jörg nennen sollte.

Answer (score 4):

... oder aber - und warum auch nicht? - du nennst den jeweiligen anderen Herrn beim ganzen Namen:

> Zu Josef: "Hey Josef, schick doch mal dem **Hans Müller** diesen Katalog, der braucht ihn dringend."
>
> Und dann zu Hans: "Hallo Hans, du, der **Josef Meier** schickt dir nachher gleich den Katalog."

Comment: Das geht einmal zu Begin einer Konversation (und ist auch gut um klar zustellen um wen es geht). Aber in einem längeren Gespräch immer beide Namen zu fühl sich falsch an.

Comment: Bei wiederholtem Auftreten würde ich einfach zu Herr(n) Meier oder einfach nur zu Meier übergehen: "Hey Hans, hat dir der Meier schon den Katalog geschickt?"

Comment: @PixelMaster - Das ist zwar vielerorts üblich, aber es wirkt respektlos. Solange sonst niemand zuhört, macht das zwar nichts, aber stell dir vor, die Tür steht auf, und Josef Meier hört zufällig mit... Um solche peinlichen Situationen zu vermeiden, ist es ratsam, stets die höflichere Form zu nehmen. Übrigens, wenn man schon meint, es hört sonst keiner zu, kann man auch jemanden, den man siezt, gegenüber Dritten mit dem Vornamen bezeichnen, also: "Hey Hans, hat dir (der) Josef schon den Katalog geschickt?" - Hört Josef unbemerkt zu, ist man damit immer noch auf der respektvolleren Seite.